# pyodbc.ProgrammingError:The definition for column <Column_name> must include a data type

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I have encountered the following problem using python to create a new table in a database in SQL Server Management studio.
I insert the following query which i printed on the console and it gives me this issue.
Does anyone know what the problem here is ?

[image]

Comment: that is impossible to rrad please post always text not images see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Apperantly i have resolved it adding rectbraces "[...]" around the column names, which is the proper way for sql server studio when the name contains special symbols. If anyone has again this problem, just to be aware :)

Comment: nobodyx can find this because the code is in a image